# How to markup an electricity rate in Schema.org?

Tags: schema.org

What are the correct entities and how to nest them to declare an electricity rate for an electricity provider?

Example:

> Provider: John Doe Provider
>
> Rate: John Doe’s Special Electricity Rate
>
> Basefee: 9,90 EUR
>
> Working Price: 0,27 EUR / kWh
>
> Rating: 5 from 5 Stars

Comment: Does [UnitPriceSpecification](https://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification) and its RDFa example help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the recommendation of ***Andrew Morton***, however, I would like to clarify some details. To identify kilowatt-hours, I recommend that you use an international identifier from UNECE. E.g.:

```html
"priceSpecification":{
"@type":"UnitPriceSpecification",
"price":"0.27",
"priceCurrency":"EUR",
"referenceQuantity": {
"@type":"QuantitativeValue",
"value":"1",
"unitCode":"KWH",
"sameAs":"http://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/cefact/recommendations/bkup_htm/add3hk.htm"
}
}
```

In the content of a web page, it may be useful to use the **[HTML element abbr](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_abbr.asp)** for an abbreviation of kilowatt-hours

Use the following recommendation for the **[price](https://schema.org/price)** property:

> Use '.' (Unicode 'FULL STOP' (U+002E)) rather than ',' to indicate a
>   decimal point. Avoid using these symbols as a readability separator.

Update 2019-09-30 related to the following question of JKB:

> ... But how to extend this example to also declare „base fee“? And, in
>   addition, set the name of the supplier?

The following markup may probably help you:

```js
{"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type":"Service",
"serviceType":"Supply of electricity",
"provider":{
"@type":"LocalBusiness",
"name":"John Doe Provider"
},
"offers":{
"@type":"Offer",
"name":"Base fee",
"price": "9.90",
"priceCurrency": "EUR",
"priceSpecification":{
"@type":"UnitPriceSpecification",
"name":"Working Price",
"price":"0.27",
"priceCurrency":"EUR",
"referenceQuantity": {
"@type":"QuantitativeValue",
"value":"1",
"unitCode":"KWH",
"sameAs":"http://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/cefact/recommendations/bkup_htm/add3hk.htm"
}
}
}
}
```

I set here the top-level type such as ***Service*** however, I do not have a clear understanding of whether this is a service or a product. Therefore you need to clearly determine whether the supply of electricity is a service or is it an intangible product.  If this is a product, then adjust this markup for the type Product.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That clarifies the „price per kilowatt hour“. But how to extend this example to also declare „base fee“? And, in addition, set the name of the supplier?

Comment: I made a correction to my post to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats what i was looking for!